# Facing issue with signal handlers for SIGTERM

Tags: c++, c, linux

My Application had already configured a `SIGTERM` handler.
Ex:

```
Signal(SIGTERM, &signalHandler);
```

I want to do some processing before shutdown and I cannot do change in existing signal handler.
To do my processing, I placed a hook like this
configured my handler as

```
signal(SIGTERM, &mySignalHandler);
```

`mySignalHandler` calls `signalHandler` later after doing its processing to make system unaffected even after the hook.

Now, considering the fact that `mySignalHandler` will be invoked, It works when `kill  $pid` once.
But if I do it twice or more time. `signalHandler` gets called. As far as I know `SIG_DFL` should be performed in this case.

Anybody knows the reason for this.

I am using “Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 8)”

[EDIT]:strange behaviour faced with test program

```
#undef _GNU_SOURCE
using namespace std;

volatile sig_atomic_t signalHandlerVar_ = false;
volatile sig_atomic_t signalHandlerSecondVar_ = false;

extern "C" void signalHandler(int)
{
    signalHandlerVar_ = true;
}

extern "C" void signalHandlerSecond(int value)
{
    signalHandlerSecondVar_ = true;
}

void* threadFunc(void*)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(signalHandlerVar_)
        {
            cout<<"signalHandler_ "<<signalHandlerVar_<<endl;
            signalHandlerVar_ = false;
        }

        if(signalHandlerSecondVar_)
        {
            cout<<"signalHandlerSecond_ "<<signalHandlerSecondVar_<<endl;
            signalHandlerSecondVar_ = false;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    ::signal(SIGTERM, &signalHandler);
    ::signal(SIGTERM, &signalHandlerSecond);
    pthread_t thread;

    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &threadFunc, NULL))
    {
        cout<<"pthread create failed"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}
```

Here problem i am facing, on every kill $pid it calls signalHandlerSecond.as i am using #undef _GNU_SOURCE and tried #undef _BSD_SOURCE.But it should reset it to SIG_DFL.

Can anybody suggest where i am doing wrong?

Comment: [The man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) says that resetting to SIG_DFL is the original Unix behavior. On Linux, it either has BSD behavior (if `_BSD_SOURCE`) or system V behavior (if source is compiled to be strictly standard). If you are compiling with `-std=cXX` as opposed to `-std=gnuXX`, then perhaps you could give compiling with GNU features a try, or define `_BSD_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 2):

From [`signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also
>   varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its
>   use: use sigaction(2) instead.  See Portability below.
>   ...
>   If the signal signum is delivered to the process, then one of the
>   following happens:
>   - ...
>   - ...
>   - If the disposition is set to a function, then first **either the
>   disposition is reset to SIG_DFL, or the signal is blocked** (see
>   Portability below), and then handler is called with argument
>   signum.  If invocation of the handler caused the signal to be
>   blocked, then the signal is unblocked upon return from the
>   handler.

On Linux, it depends on how you compile your source. Since your program isn't aborted from any following `kill`, I suspect it uses the BSD semantics as described later under *Portability*

> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> ```
>   * The kernel's signal() system call provides System V semantics.
>
>   * By default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function
>      does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls
>      sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics.  This default
>      behavior is provided as long as the _BSD_SOURCE feature test macro
>      is defined.  By default, _BSD_SOURCE is defined; it is also
>      implicitly defined if one defines _GNU_SOURCE, and can of course be
>      explicitly defined.
>
>     On glibc 2 and later, if the _BSD_SOURCE feature test macro is not
>      defined, then signal() provides System V semantics.  (The default
>      implicit definition of _BSD_SOURCE is not provided if one invokes
>      gcc(1) in one of its standard modes (-std=xxx or -ansi) or defines
>      various other feature test macros such as _POSIX_SOURCE,
>      _XOPEN_SOURCE, or _SVID_SOURCE; see feature_test_macros(7).)
> ```

---

To force System V behaviour, you need to define one of `_POSIX_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, or `_SVID_SOURCE`, e.g.

```
gcc -D_SVID_SOURCE -Wall -g -pthread test.c
```

This doesn't seem to work with g++, though. When you compile with

```
g++ -D_SVID_SOURCE -Wall -g -pthread test.cpp
```

you still get the BSD behaviour. Adding `-v`

```
g++ -v -D_SVID_SOURCE -Wall -g -pthread test.cpp
```

reveals

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu **-D_GNU_SOURCE** -D_REENTRANT -D _SVID_SOURCE test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase a -g -Wall -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/cc3MpiO2.s

which is not present, when compiling with gcc.
You can suppress this with an additional `-U_GNU_SOURCE`

```
g++ -U_GNU_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -Wall -g -pthread test.cpp
```

Finally, this gives us System V behaviour, which means the signal handler is reset to `SIG_DFL` after the first signal delivery.

Comment: "the library resets the signal so that the default action is performed if the same signal occurs again".So signalHandler should not be caleed.it gives me the impression that after disposition it sets SIG_DFL as the one i had configured earlier.So, doest kernel do such book-keeping.

Comment: The kernel doesn't do any book-keeping. It stores only one signal handler per signal. `signal` returns the previous signal handler.

Comment: Your quote describes the System V behaviour. This is not what Linux does, unless you explicitly request by doing `#undef _BSD_SOURCE` or use `-std=...`. Try yourself and compile your program with System V semantics. Then you will see the behaviour, you quoted.

Comment: edidted the post, tried with Sysytem V semantic,now facing some strange issue

Comment: It seems `_BSD_SOURCE` is not explicitly defined, but implicitly through `_GNU_SOURCE`, so the man page is not correct in this case. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function mySignalHandler(), you have to call signal() again :

The first time (anywhere in your code) :

```
signal(SIGTERM, &mySignalHandler);
```

Then in your function :

```
void mySignalHandler() {
    //your code here

    signal(SIGTERM, &mySignalHandler);
}
```

Like this, the next time SIGTERM is catched, the program will enter in mySignalHandler()

Hope it's help you.

Comment: really sigaction should be used for this

Comment: Thanks.Will try hopefully this work.But why the signalHandler is getting called, if it has been disposed to SIG_DFL.That is what i want to know.does kernel do any book keeping.